# Display Time in Label 1 and Display Date in Label 2

Tags: vb.net

How can I Display time in military clock format to label 1  and Display date in Longdate format to label 2 regards guys.

```
    Label6.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()
    Label3.Text = Now.ToLongTimeString.ToString()
```

Comment: Label6.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()

Comment: And what is the error? Please edit your post and add info there.

Comment: theres no error @lucio the time cant display

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Me.Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
Me.Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString
```

Comment: Don't forget about the '()' at the end :)

Comment: Label6.Text = Format(Now, "Long Date")
        Label7.Text = Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")
this codes .. got it..